# If not being ignored

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'm writing an if not statement. When I'm debugging it looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

```
infotypeid = 68
GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar = 68
```

but its still hitting exit sub:

```
If (Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar OrElse Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar2) Then
   Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: What is value of `GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar2`?

Comment: it's 43 - So both 68 and 43 should go through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `AndAlso` instead of `OrElse` since the former is pointless:

```
If (Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar AndAlso Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar2) Then
```

Now the `If` will be entered on those two `eInfoTypeID` values. With `OrElse` you would check if it's **not** `eInfoTypeID.myvar` and if that's `true`(which means it *is* `eInfoTypeID.myvar`) you check if it's something other.

Another option to increase readability is to use a collection to lookup:

```
Dim wrongInfoTypes = {GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar, GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar2}
If Not wrongInfoTypes.Contains(infotypeid) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Ah, of course. I keep flitting between c# and vb.net. These simple things get me every bloody time. Cheers

Comment: @TomBeech: you could increase readability with `Enumerable.Contains`. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That's the issue your condition should use `AndAlso` instead of `OrElse`.

```
If (Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar AndAlso _
    Not infotypeid = GlobalEnums.eInfoTypeID.myvar2) Then
   Exit Sub
End If
```